# XmlNode.RemoveChild has no effect in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

The following function "works" in that no exceptions are raised and the xml document is saved to disk. However, none of the nodes I've removed are actually deleted from the document:

```
function RemoveInvalidFileNodes($file, $substring){


[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file

$nodes=$xml.SelectNodes("//File")
$substring = [regex]::Escape($substring)

foreach ($node in $nodes) {


         if ($node.Name -match $substring) 

                {
                 $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
                }

}

Write-Host $xml.OuterXml

$xml.Save 
}
```

I've been banging my head on this for hours.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that instead of actually saving the file you are telling powershell to show you definitions of the function save. When I've ran your code I've got following output in the end.

```
OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                                                                  
-------------------                                                                                                                                                                  
void Save(string filename)                                                                                                                                                           
void Save(System.IO.Stream outStream)                                                                                                                                                
void Save(System.IO.TextWriter writer)                                                                                                                                               
void Save(System.Xml.XmlWriter w)
```

To actually save the file you need to change last line to something like this:

```
$xml.Save("C:\my2.xml")
```

I've tried your function on the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Files>
   <File Name="Hello" Surname="Zi" />
   <File Name="Hellow" Surname="Zi" />
</Files>
```

With following calling code:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
RemoveInvalidFileNodes -file "C:\my.xml" -substring "Hello"
```

And it deleted all file nodes.